# Как извлечь xml параметры в Post запросе. GlassFish

Tags: java, xml, glassfish

Идет заголовок запроса потом параметры в xml
то-есть не

param1=one&param2=two

а xml строка

```
request.getParameter("nameOfParam");
```

не будет работать.

Мне нужен способ достать строку параметров.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вопрос не понятен, что вы хотите получить и как достать? Есть ли пример запроса?

```
request.getParameter("nameOfParam");
```

Даст вам как раз строку параметров, не важно post или get.

Если вам нужно уже из XML достать какой-то параметр, то используйте любой удобный вариант

- org.w3c.Document + XPath
- StAX

Примеров разбора XML в интернете и на SO много.